# Is there a way to create a Dropbox link that opens a file or a folder in the native app?

Tags: dropbox

Basically, what I would like to do is to create a link from a web application that will open a Dropbox file from appropriate Dropbox native app. Google Drive for example allows you to re-format the unique URL for a file such as https://docs.google.com/blablabla which you can retrieve from their API, into googledrive://docs.google.com/blablabla and lets you open the file in Google Drive native app.

I have tried dropbox:// URLs with no success, and have not found any existing conversation on this despite running cross multiple conversations on the same subject for Google Drive or Evernote. Please let me know if it is possible to somehow generate this via API or based on the folder structure etc.

Thanks!

Comment: The Dropbox app doesn't currently offer this but I'll be sure to pass this along as feedback.